# why laravel post error show when already added post method in routes?

Tags: laravel

[image: post error show by laravel, when i have already added routes of post methods in web.php,]

```php
Route::post('user',[employeelogin::class,'em']);
```

this route for handle post request( coming by page) in my web.php,

```
<form class="form w-100"  action="{{url('/user')}}" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

(this from with method to call the route)

```
            [laravel post error][1]
```

Comment: Did you clear config or do you have another route with the same path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `Route::post()` for your route, but then submitting a GET request to the URL.

Either switch `Route::post()` to `Route::get()`, or change your request to POST.

Answer (score 0):

Can You Please Run Command "php artisan optimize" And "php artisan optimize:clear". i think its comes